# How do I calculate the difference between rows in a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new here and excited to join the community! I am having a problem with an exercise that I came up with, but I am trying to solve it since some days, so I thought it is the right time to ask you for some help.

I have a 2d array and would like to calculate the differences between all of the positions in the columns and then store them in another 2d array. The initial array has 4 rows and 3 columns.
Like 4 points with 3 coordinates in 3d.

This is what I came up with, any help much appreciated! Thanks a lot!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CountingTheDifference {

public static String loop(double[][] twoDArray) {

    int length = twoDArray.length;

    double[][] differences = new double[length][length];

    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[i].length; j++) {
                differences[i][0] = twoDArray[j][0] - twoDArray[j++][0];

            }
        } else if (i == 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[i].length; j++) {
                differences[i][1] = twoDArray[j][1] - twoDArray[j++][1];
            }
        }
        else {
            for ( int j = 0; j < twoDArray[i].length; j++) {
                differences[i][2] = twoDArray[j][2] - twoDArray[j][2];
            }
        }
    }

    return Arrays.deepToString(differences);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[][] twoArray = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12,}};
    System.out.println(loop(twoArray));
}
}
```

Please help!
Dorotha

Comment: I can't understand your problem. Differences between what?

Comment: hey Enrico, in substracting the elements betweens every column in the array. So twoArray[0][0] minus twoArray[1][0] and so forth and storing it in a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've kept your code in tact as much as possible, using the 2D double array as in the provided code.

```
public static String loop(double[][] twoDArray) {

    int columns = twoDArray.length;
    int rows = twoDArray[0].length;

    double[][] differences = new double[columns][rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            // Absolute difference between the value of this column compared to the previous
            // -1 if this is the first column
            // Prints: [[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0]]
            if (i == 0) {
                differences[i][j] = -1;
            } else {
                differences[i][j] = Math.abs(twoDArray[i][j] - twoDArray[i - 1][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return Arrays.deepToString(differences);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] twoArray = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}; // Note that I removed a comma.
    System.out.println(loop(twoArray));
}
```

Comment: Hi Wouter, thanks a lot for your help! 
So what I am trying to do is with having this array: double[][] twoArray = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
I would get an array that has differences (substraction) betweend the the elements in the columns:
differences[][] = {{-3, -3, 3}, {-3, -3, 3,}, {-3, -3, 3}};
I hope it explains it better?

Comment: I've edited my answer. If it does not suffice, feel free to comment on it :)

Comment: I've edited my answer again to remove the suggestion to use streams. Using streams to access different values in the same array proved to result in bulky code.